# Show equality in a probability problem. Help understanding steps in a solution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Possion variables with parameters
>   $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Show that
>
> **i)** $X+Y$ is Possion with parameter $\lambda +\mu.$
>
> **ii)** The conditional distribution of $X$, given that $X+Y=n$, is binomial and find the parameters.

**The book solution:**
Let us notice that for $X$ and $Y$ non-negative independent random variables, then

$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}P(X=n-k)P(Y=k), \tag{1}$$

so in our specific case of Possion random variables we have

$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{e^{\lambda}\lambda^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^k}{k!}=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\lambda^{n-k}\mu^k=\frac{e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}(\lambda+\mu)^n}{n!}.\tag{2}$$

For the second part of the question:

$$P(X=k|X+Y=n)=\frac{P(X=k,X+Y=n)}{P(X+Y=n)}=\\ \frac{P(X=k)P(Y=n-k)}{P(X+Y=n)}= {n\choose k}\frac{\lambda^k\mu^{n-k}}{(\mu+\lambda)^n},$$

Hence the conditional distribution is binomial with parameters $n$ and $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}.$

---

**Questions:**

1. What is (1) telling me and why does it hold?
2. How can I compute the second sum in (2)? (Need to know the arithmetic behind it
3. In **i)**, we set $Y=k$ and in **ii)** we set $X=k,$ why is it okay to do this? Could we have set $X=k$ in the first as well?

Comment: 1. We have $\displaystyle P(X+Y=n)=P\left(\ \sqcup_{0\le k\le n}X=k\text{ and }Y=n-k\ \right)= \sum_{0\le k\le n}P\left(\ X=k\text{ and }Y=n-k\ \right)=\sum_{0\le k\le n}P(\ X=k\ )\cdot P(\ Y=n-k\ )$. 2. That is the binomial formula. 3. is unclear.

Comment: I  don't think you read my questions 2 and 3 correctly. And I don't understand your notations for question 1.

Comment: The notation $\sqcup$ stays for the disjoint union of sets to follow. (I always have problems with the brackets in 'Jax.) The disjoint union "jumps over" $P$ and becomes a sum. Then we use independence to replace the "and" by the dot / by the product. This was one (except for the "telling part"). Two. The second sum is the expanded version of $(\lambda+\mu)^n$, as shown by the binomial formula. So i could read correctly (and understand the message one could extract rather from the formulas). Three. Is unclear, since $k$ is not defined, and "setting" $X=k$ made no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In order to have $X+Y=n$, you need to have $Y$ take some value between $0$ and $n$ (let's call that value $k$), and then you need to have $X=n-k$ in order to satisfy $X+Y=n$. Since these are disjoint events, their probabilities need to be added up, leading to $$\sum_{k=0}^n P(X=n-k\cap Y=k)$$Finally, using the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $$P(X=n-k\cap Y=k)=P(X=n-k)P(Y=k).$$
2. This is the binomial theorem, which says that for any $a,b$ and natural number $n$,
   $$
   (a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}
   $$
   Just let $a=\mu$ and $b=\lambda$.
3. You could also have used $X=k$ in the first part. Then it would look like $\sum_{k=0}^n P(X=k)P(Y=n-k)$. This corresponds to adding up the numbers in the reverse order, which gives you the same result. 
   The $k$ is unrelated between the two problems: in the first, it is just a "dummy variable" which we introduce in order to write out the summation, and in the second, it represents a value which $X$ can take conditional on $X+Y=n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, cleared out a lot of questions. I realise I shouldn't even have asked 2. But in your first answer, you say that "Since these are disjoint events, their probabilities need to be added up..." But you are summing the PRODUCT of their probabilities. Is this because, for a given value, say $Y=k=1$ it follows that the event $\{X+Y=n\}$ is equivalent wtih $\{X=n-1\}\cup\{Y=1\}$, but $\{X=n-1\}$ and $\{Y=1\}$ are pairwise disjoint so $P(X=n-1\cup Y=1)=P(X=n-1) + P(Y=k)?$ But in my case $k=0,1,...,n$, hence the sum?

Comment: @Parseval See my edit to (1). You've got the right idea, but in your comment, you should have $\cap$ instead of $\cup$ (intersection, not union), so that $P(X=n-k\cap Y=k)=P(X=n-k)P(Y=k)$.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Great replies, thank you!